# Can't integrate NTLM and JAVA

Tags: java, liferay, ntlm, samba

I can't integrate NTLM auth in my web app. I use [this](http://ntlmv2auth.sourceforge.net/ntlmv2-filter/) library for connecting to Samba-server. I don't understand what some of the parameters mean:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>ntlm-account</param-name>
    <!-- Who is this user; where is it configured? -->
    <param-value>TECHUSER$@ACME.CORP</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>ntlm-password</param-name>
    <param-value>test1234</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I don't understand what I must configure with ntlm-account user.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an account that has access to do a search in the ldap directory, basically an account to login to the domain controller of your NT/AD domain